# How to get update alert for google play store beta testing version of my android app

Tags: android

How to get update alert for beta testing version of my app which is in google play store.

Comment: com.github.rampo.updatechecker:library:2.1.8 library works for production build but same library does not work for beta testing build.

Answer (score 0):

A user being part of the beta test pool will get an app update notification. If you want more, for instance to have a notification coming from the app itself when it was updated you need to implement it yourself into your app.

You have the choice to do it with a [simple notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) or by implementing a [push notification](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: Thanks Galex,   but how to check inside app itself that app new version is available or not in play store under beta testing  ?

Comment: which library or code i need to use for checking wether new version of app is available or not in google play store.

Comment: You can store a String in SharedPreferences and triggered by a push notification, check if the app version is smaller than the one already stored and then update it.